# In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(*)?

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
select column_name, count(column_name)
from table
group by column_name
having count(column_name) > 1;
```

What would be the difference if I replaced all calls to `count(column_name)` to `count(*)`?

This question was inspired by [How do I find duplicate values in a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232/how-do-i-find-duplicate-values-in-a-table-in-oracle).

---

To clarify the accepted answer (and maybe my question), replacing `count(column_name)` with `count(*)` would return an extra row in the result that contains a `null` and the count of `null` values in the column.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

`count(*)` counts NULLs and `count(column)` does not

[edit] added this code so that people can run it

```
create table #bla(id int,id2 int)
insert #bla values(null,null)
insert #bla values(1,null)
insert #bla values(null,1)
insert #bla values(1,null)
insert #bla values(null,1)
insert #bla values(1,null)
insert #bla values(null,null)

select count(*),count(id),count(id2)
from #bla
```

results
7   3   2

Comment: Just curious: if you have a row with _all_ NULLs, would count(*) still count it, or is just count(column) for all columns?

Comment: Is this standard accross DBMSs?

Comment: DB2 v9 is issuing a warning:
SQLSTATE 01003: Null values were eliminated from the argument of a column function

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you have a non-nullable column such as ID, then count(ID) will significantly improve performance over count(*).

Comment: @tsilb: The answer posted by @Alan states "count(*) is computed by looking at the indexes on the table in question rather than the actual data rows" which, if true, invalidates your comment. I appreciate that @Alan may be wrong but I'm interested in the source of your information in order to find out which is correct.

Comment: @tsilb: Many modern query optimizers will optimize count(*) to use indexes when it makes sense to.

Comment: What is interesting is that this results in count(DISTINCT column name) counting only non-null distinct values, whereas SELECT DISTINCT also returns a null row if there is one or more null values.

Comment: @SQLMenace What if i use count(1)? Where does that leave me?

Comment: @renegadeMind: if your target is just to check the table is not empty while looking for specific conditions you can do this

`if Exists (Select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'SalesChannel_PartyRole')`

Comment: The ought to be no improvement in using count(column_name) over count(\*) where column_name is not null. any benefit would come from using an index scan instead of a table scan, but the optimiser can choose to do so for count(*) anyway. In Oracle this has been the case for a very long time.

Comment: It's not correct to say that "count(\*) counts nulls" -- the presence or absence of nulls is irrelevant as count(\*) counts the number of rows regardless of their content.

Answer (score 37):

Another minor difference, between using * and a specific column, is that in the column case you can add the keyword DISTINCT, and restrict the count to distinct values:

```
select column_a, count(distinct column_b)
from table
group by column_a
having count(distinct column_b) > 1;
```

Comment: Should the group by column and the one being counted be different? otherwise you would get nothing from this query

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I hadn't noticed that they were the same column in the example.  I'll update the post.

Comment: The code is plain useless. `select column_a, count(distinct column_a) from table group by column_a having count(distinct column_a) > 1;` makes it meaningful.

Answer (score 19):

A further and perhaps subtle difference is that in some database implementations the count(*) is computed by looking at the indexes on the table in question rather than the actual data rows.  Since no specific column is specified, there is no need to bother with the actual rows and their values (as there would be if you counted a specific column). Allowing the database to use the index data can be significantly faster than making it count "real" rows.

Comment: +1 Yes, certainly true for Oracle, and for PostgreSQL from 9.2 onwards.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Can you provider a pointer to documentation (especially for postgresql) where this is mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: @Bhushan here's you go https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans

Answer (score 13):

The explanation in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), helps to explain this:

> COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group, including NULL values and duplicates.
>
> COUNT(expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.

So count(*) includes nulls, the other method doesn't.

Comment: For SQL newbs: To what help file are you referring?

Answer (score 11):

We can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to illustrate the difference with a simple query.  The Users table in Stack Overflow's database has columns that are often left blank, like the user's Website URL.

```
-- count(column_name) vs. count(*)
-- Illustrates the difference between counting a column
-- that can hold null values, a  'not null' column, and  count(*)

select count(WebsiteUrl), count(Id), count(*) from Users
```

If you run the query above in the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), you'll see that the count is the same for `count(Id)` and `count(*)`because the `Id` column doesn't allow `null` values.  The `WebsiteUrl` count is much lower, though, because that column allows `null`.

Answer (score 2):

- The COUNT(*) sentence indicates SQL Server to return all the rows from a table, including NULLs.
- COUNT(column_name) just retrieves the rows having a non-null value on the rows.

Please see following code for test executions SQL Server 2008:

```
-- Variable table
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
      CustomerId int NULL 
    , Name nvarchar(50) NULL
)

-- Insert some records for tests
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( NULL, 'Pedro')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( 1, 'Juan')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( 2, 'Pablo')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( 3, 'Marcelo')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( NULL, 'Leonardo')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES( 4, 'Ignacio')

-- Get all the collumns by indicating *
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS 'AllRowsCount'
FROM    @Table

-- Get only content columns ( exluce NULLs )
SELECT  COUNT(CustomerId) AS 'OnlyNotNullCounts'
FROM    @Table
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically the `COUNT(*)` function return all the rows from a table whereas `COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)` does not; that is it excludes null values which everyone here have also answered here.
But the most interesting part is to make queries and database optimized it is better to use `COUNT(*)` unless doing multiple counts or a complex query rather than `COUNT(COLUMN_NAME)`. Otherwise, it will really lower your DB performance while dealing with a huge number of data.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)` – Returns the total number of records in a table (Including NULL valued records).

`COUNT(Column Name)` – Returns the total number of Non-NULL records. It means that, it ignores counting NULL valued records in that particular column.

Answer (score 2):

Further elaborating upon the answer given by @SQLMeance and @Brannon making use of `GROUP BY` clause which has been mentioned by OP but not present in answer by @SQLMenace

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( 
id INT 
);
```

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES 
(1), 
(2), 
(NULL), 
(2), 
(NULL), 
(3), 
(1), 
(4), 
(NULL), 
(2);
```

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
| NULL |
|    2 |
| NULL |
|    3 |
|    1 |
|    4 |
| NULL |
|    2 |
+------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) FROM table1 GROUP BY id;
```

```
+------+----------+
| id   | COUNT(*) |
+------+----------+
|    1 |        2 |
|    2 |        3 |
| NULL |        3 |
|    3 |        1 |
|    4 |        1 |
+------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, `COUNT(*)` counts the number of occurrences of each type of `id` including `NULL`

```
SELECT id, COUNT(id) FROM table1 GROUP BY id;
```

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | COUNT(id) |
+------+-----------+
|    1 |         2 |
|    2 |         3 |
| NULL |         0 |
|    3 |         1 |
|    4 |         1 |
+------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, `COUNT(id)` counts the number of occurrences of each type of `id` but does not count the number of occurrences of `NULL`

```
SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table1 GROUP BY id;
```

```
+------+--------------------+
| id   | COUNT(DISTINCT id) |
+------+--------------------+
| NULL |                  0 |
|    1 |                  1 |
|    2 |                  1 |
|    3 |                  1 |
|    4 |                  1 |
+------+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` counts the number of occurrences of each type of `id` only once (does not count duplicates) and also does not count the number of occurrences of `NULL`

Answer (score -1):

It is best to use

```
Count(1) in place of column name or *
```

to count the number of rows in a table, it is faster than any format because it never go to check the column name into table exists or not

Comment: Incorrect for Oracle at least, and for other RDBMS's too I suspect. Internally count(1) is transformed to count\(*). In particular, performance of count(\*) is not adversely affected by the size of the rows, which is a common misconception.

Comment: This is true for SQL Server. As @Ali Adravi said, `COUNT(*)` in comparison with `COUNT(columnName)` will not go to check column value, because it just enumerate rows. But `COUNT(columnName)` is slower even the `count` applied on an `id` column! At least in SQL Server, of course.

Answer (score -2):

There is no difference if one column is fix in your table, if you want to use more than one column than you have to specify that how much columns you required to count......

Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the previous answers, `Count(*)` counts even the `NULL` columns, whereas `count(Columnname)` counts only if the column has values.

It's always best practice to avoid `*` (`Select *`, `count *`, …)

Comment: It's not at all a best practice to avoid `COUNT(*)`