# In SQL is there a difference between count(*) and count(<fieldname>)

Tags: sql

Pretty self explanatory question. Is there any reason to use one or the other?

Comment: Both http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59322/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-count-and-countx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count come up when I search.

Comment: I did a search for "sql difference between count" and neither of those were in the first 10 results.

Comment: @BillTheLiz, that first one is different [uses count(fixed-val), not count(column)] although it references an earlier one that does use column. In any case, the second one IS an exact match so I'm voting for close.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Count(*) counts all records, including nulls, whereas Count(fieldname) does not include nulls.

Comment: It does not include rows where the specific fieldname is not null

Answer (score 6):

Select count(*) selects any row, select count(field) selects rows where this field is not null.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to improve performance (i.e. be a complete performance Nazi), you might want to do neither.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MyTable WHERE ...
```

Comment: I've always thought the same, but assumed that by now most DBMS's would automatically translate COUNT(*) into the most efficient lookup possible, given how ubiquitous that statement is. I've no evidence either for or against it though.

Comment: I'm sure that this would probably have the same perf as COUNT(Clustered_Index_Column), since it has to actually read the CI regardless. But it was a cool trick that the DBA put in the SQL standards. That is, don't select a column by name if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

This puzzled me for a while too.

In MySQL at least `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows where every (*) value in the row is not null. Just `COUNT`ing a column will count the number of rows where that column is not null.

In terms of performance using a single column would be slightly faster,

Comment: In SQL, can you insert a row that is entirely NULLs, or must something be non-null in every row?  If you can insert such a row, is it then not counted?

Comment: @A. Rex:  Standard SQL says that COUNT(*) counts all rows, period.  As for whether you can insert a row of all NULLs, you cannot if you have declared a primary key on that table.

Comment: Actually, its the opposite regarding performance. At least in MyISAM, COUNT(*) is cached and performs much faster. In InnoDB they'll perform the same.

Comment: @Bill Karwin: That's what I thought.  However, that seems to disagree with @Ross's post.  COUNT(*) either counts all rows, or all rows which are not entirely null.  If it's possible for them to differ, COUNT(*) can only do one ...

Answer (score -1):

count(*) is faster if table type is MyISAM with no WHERE statement. With WHERE the speed will be the same for MyISAM and InnoDB.