# COUNT(id) vs. COUNT(*) in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, count

Is there a difference between the following queries, assuming there is a primary field 'id' in the table (as in speed, etc)?

```
SELECT COUNT(id) 
  FROM table
```

vs.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM table
```

Comment: Have a look at [Count(*) vs Count(col)](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/) at www.mysqlperformanceblog.com, they discuss this topic for various 'col' types (NOT NULL or not, with index, etc) and this for MyISAM and InnoDB tables.

Comment: You can look onto these threads http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433913/in-sql-is-there-a-difference-between-count-and-countfieldname http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is about MySQL, but for what it's worth, `count(*)` is recommended for Oracle, which goes to show that **the answer to this can be database dependent** (see comment above from BalusC).

Since a lot of databases (MS-SQL, MySQL) have information schema tables that hold various types of metadata, there are bound to be differences if one syntax is simply looking up a readily-available value, and another is going straight to the table.

At the end of day: try different options, and see what EXPLAIN is telling you is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: It seems to me more and more that the way to go is either to use an ORM (and hope it optimizes for all cases), or to write SQL for exactly *one* database engine and forget about the rest.

Answer (score 2):

One important different is that `Count(*)` and `Count($col_name)` **can show different outputs** if the `$col_name` column is nullable, since null values don't get counted by `Count`.

Comment: I think the question refers to the PK when it says "id", so NOT NULL is assumed, as well as a PRI index.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is several years old but I don't see any evidence on which one to use, so I will post here my findings.

Executing explain in MySql Workbench for an InnoDB table on MySql 5.7 I see the following:

[image: Executing count(*)]

[image: Executing count(id)]

As you can see, both results are identical, so for this scenario both expressions are equivalent