# Is COUNT(fld) faster than COUNT(*)?

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [COUNT(id) vs. COUNT(*) in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697137/countid-vs-count-in-mysql)

Short but simple: in MySQL, would a `SELECT COUNT(fld) AS count FROM tbl` be faster than `SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl` as I understand `*` is the "all" selector in MySQL.

Does `COUNT(*)` select all rows to compute a count, and therefore make a query like `SELECT(id)` less expensive? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697137/countid-vs-count-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697137/countid-vs-count-in-mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `count(*)` is faster than `count(fld)` (in the cases where there is a difference at all).

The `count(fld)` has to consider the data in the field, as it counts all non-null values.

The `count(*)` only counts the number of records, so it doesn't need access to the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM tbl
```

The above query doesn't even count the rows assuming there's no `WHERE` clause, it reads directly from the table cache.  Specifying a field instead of `*` forces SQL to actually count the rows, so it's much faster to use `*` when there's no `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1):

> `*` is the “all” selector in MySQL

That's true when you SELECT columns, where the `*` is a shortcut for the whole column list.

`SELECT *` becomes `SELECT foo, bar`.

But `COUNT(*)` is not expanded to `COUNT(foo,bar)` which is nonsensical in SQL. `COUNT` is an aggregate function which normally needs one value per selected row.