# Count especific table rows in mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, web

I want to count how many rows I have in a mysql table and display it in html.

For example:

There is: Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5, Item 6

If Item 1 and Item 2 are filled, I want a html code to say - 2 items in row

any ideas?

Comment: what's the problem in using `Count(*)` function with `Where` clause?

Comment: I dont know how to use it 100% sry... im new to this

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple

```
Select count(*) from table
```

or If you want not null values

```
Select count(item) from table
```

Answer (score 1):

IF its total rows you are after, then as Nishant mentioned above you could do something like this

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE myfield='myvalue'";
```

<strike>I am counting all the ids, because it will reduce the time taken to calculate the total instead of '*' and</strike>

Thanks to Nico, **count(*) and count(column) are not so different considering performance**. [Here is a comparision](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/)

Use a where condition to narrow your total as you require.

Comment: `COUNT(column)` and `COUNT(*)` do not necessarily have different performances, it is very database specific. In certain cases `COUNT(*)` can actually be faster. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697137/countid-vs-count-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, Nico, I use to think it was faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count only rows which are *filled* (meaning, which are *not null*), you should add a small WHERE clause, or specify the column of interest in the `count()` function:

- using where

  SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE fieldx IS NOT NULL
- specifying the field of interest

  SELECT count(fieldx) FROM mytable

in this last solution, `count()` will only take into account not-null *fieldx* values.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the number of rows of your query using the function [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

So if you have a SELECT statement (to select which items you want), you just have to call mysql_num_rows() after doing the query. Example from php.net:

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
```

Comment: NEWER do it this way, my boy. If you need a number, request exactly that number, not ALL rows to count it later.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by filled? Anyway, if by 'filled' you mean that some specific field has a NOT NULL value you could do something like this:

```
$sqlConn = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$sqlConn->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 IS NOT NULL AND field2 IS NOT NULL');
echo 'You have ' . $sqlConn->affected_rows . ' rows.';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a very intricated way of doing a `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: You're right, I just mistakenly supposed he also needed to extract the data from the table, sooner or later.