# COUNT(*) vs. COUNT(1) vs COUNT(column) with WHERE condition performance in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a query in Cassandra

```
select count(pk1) from tableA where pk1=xyz
```

Table is :

```
create table tableA 
(
    pk1 uuid,
    pk2 int,
    pk3 text,
    pk4 int,
    fc1 int,
    fc2 bigint,
    ....
    fcn blob,
    primary key (pk1, pk2 , pk3 , pk4)
```

The query is executed often and takes up to 2s to execute.

I am wondering if there will be any performance gain if refactoring to:

```
select count(1) from tableA where pk = xyz
```

Comment: Do you need an exact count?  You can get estimates with nodetool.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), there is no difference between count(1) and count(*).

Generally speaking COUNT(1) and COUNT(*) will both return the number of rows that match the condition specified in your query

This is in line with how traditional SQL databases are implemented.

> COUNT ( { [ [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression ] | * } )

Count(1) is a condition that always evaluates to true.

Also, Count(Column_name) only returns the *Non-Null* values.

Since in your case because of where condition the "Non-null" is a non-factor, I don't think there will be any difference in performance in using one over the other. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6524425/3921053) answer tried confirming the same using some performance tests.

Comment: Excellent response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general COUNT is not at all recommended in Cassandra . As it’s going to scan through multiple nodes and get your answer back . And I’m not sure the count you get is really consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to the community! Generally speaking, you are correct about `COUNT()` with C*. I explained it in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6897/. But for the case above, it won't trigger a table scan because it's restricted to a single partition so will only scan the rows in that partition. Cheers!