# MySQL - Count the total number of a row without `Full Table Scans` and `WHERE` a condition

Tags: mysql

I am using the following query to fetch a total number of rows from MySQL but it used `Full table scans`. I just want to avoid full table scans.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as total_rows FROM <table_name>;
```

Please consider that I don't want to use the `WHERE` condition. `id` is my PK. This link may help you for better understanding https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nvyUHkzjWlCji8rZoH0aMq9pqSSDMqJO.

Is there any way to fetch a total number of rows without `Full table scans`?

Comment: Query has to count every row so a full table scan is appropriate - why is this a problem for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Fastest way to count number of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060366/mysql-fastest-way-to-count-number-of-rows)

Comment: @P.Salmon - I just want to optimize my query. Plz tell me is it possible without full table scans?

Comment: @PinalPatel Is `id` your PK? could you show us your execute plan?

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes, `id` is my PK & I've edited my question for better understanding.

Comment: The query in the image is not the same as the query in the question - i'm not suggesting the difference is substantive but still..and read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697137/countid-vs-count-in-mysql

Comment: My fastest way of getting total rows from a table is using `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM Table` ..

Comment: @P.Salmon I've edited the image. Plz can you check?

Comment: The image shows the query is doing a full index scan?

Comment: P.Samlo Is there any difference between the full index scan & full table scan?

Comment: I know about table scan but don't know about index scan

Comment: You should research mysql full index scan vs full table scan. I have a feeling your query is optimized but I guess you could check by removing the index and trying it.

Comment: @P.Salmon Thank you so much for giving me the right guidance!