# difference between count(*) and count(columnName)

Tags: mysql, count

I would like to know what are the differences between using:

```
SELECT email, COUNT( email ) AS total
FROM `newsletter`
GROUP BY email having total>1
```

or

```
SELECT count(*) as total, email 
FROM 'newsletter' 
GROUP BY email having total > 1
```

Both give same results but what else is counting `count(*)` than the emails?

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2511/630 explains in relation to the ANSI standard

Comment: possible duplicate of [In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count) and many others

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's at least one difference.

- They may return different results if `email` can contain `NULL`.

For more information, see [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/04/10/count-vs-countcol/).

Comment: +1 fot the link, but why do you think that count(email) cannot use the coverage indexes?

Comment: @newtover: I didn't know about that, but Peter says so, and he knows far more than I do :-)

Comment: Peter says that you will just need another index for the query he describes, which is though not the case for the query of the OP.

Comment: @newtover: indeed. Removed that item.

Answer (score 2):

COUNT(*) counts all rows WHEREAS COUNT(columnname) counts non-NULLs only.

Answer (score 2):

`count(*)` allows the database to use an index for counting, so it can do performance-improvements. as you said, the result is the same in most cases, but:

- `count(column)` only counts non-null-rows

so in colusion: if you have to mess around with null-values, use `count(column)`, otherwise use `count(*)` for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT COUNT(*)` counts all ROWS

`SELECT COUNT(email)` counts all VALUES (non-NULL values)

In your case, if all rows contain values, both results may be the same. But it can make a difference in performance, but this depends on table volumne, storage engine, indexes...