# SQL getting row count optimization

Tags: sql, database-performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(*)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count)
>   [Count() vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

I have big tables which keep long texts for example email content or news. And my question
is there any difference for performance for counting table rows :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name

SELECT COUNT(t.id) FROM table_name as t
```

Which one is better? or the latter one will be optimized by query optimizer? Is there any documentation regarding this?

Comment: Assuming `id` is a non nullable column (looks like the PK). They should be the same in any decent DBMS

Comment: @juergend - COUNT(*) and COUNT(1) are synonyms.  But COUNT(id) has different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are different.

`COUNT(*)` will retrieve all values (even the `NULL` values count).
`COUNT(t.id)` doesn't count the `NULL` values.

---

In terms of performance, they are the same (the query optimizer is smart).

Comment: In terms of performance they are only categorically the same for non nullable columns. If the column is not nullable then the QO can choose a narrower index that does not even contain the specified column or (for MySQL - can't remember which storage engine) use the cached value that does not require a table access at all.

Answer (score 1):

Query plan looks the same, but in testing, using * is faster (slightly).

Nulls are not taking into account when specifying a column name though.