# So what IS the best way to check if a row exists? EXISTS, COUNT or num_rows?

Tags: php, mysql

If your only goal is to check if a row exists in php **(true or false)**, what is the best way to do it?

**Option 1?**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows == 1) 
    // one user, like it should be.

else 
  // do something else
```

**Option 2?**

```
$query = mysql_query("select count(1) from users where id = 1")

if (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1)
    // one user, like it should be.

else 
  // do something else
```

**Option 3?**

```
$query = mysql_query("something like SELECT EXISTS( SELECT */1/COUNT(*)/etc. ...)")

if (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1)
    // one user, like it should be.

else 
  // do something else
```

**Beter option 4?**

you name it.

**Subquestions**

- `COUNT(*), COUNT(1) or COUNT(id)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL getting row count optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852753/sql-getting-row-count-optimization)

Comment: @mario: It's related but not the same. Here it is asked to find out if count=0 or >0, not the exact count.

Comment: @ypercube: The other duplicates linked there cover that. And more exist on the COUNT vs EXISTS issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table

Comment: @mario: Thanks for the link. But, how would you get the result using php? It is not JUST about the mysql, also about the php part.

Comment: @SuperSpy: The `SELECT EXISTS (subquery)` needs different treatment in PHP as it will always return one row, with either 1 or 0 (True or False).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 3 is the fastest way to check if a row exists if you are using MySQL:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = 1)")

if (mysql_result($query, 0) == 1)
    // one user, like it should be.

else 
  // do something else
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the question refers more the code itself then the time involved, so using his query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '1'");
//if result not returned(false) from Mysql return False Else True
//This is just example and you can do anything you need in side the if()
if(!$result) {
//or return some error or redirect to another piece of code
return FALSE;
} else {
//or do some other php/mysql magic
//if there is a result you have the row to work with of needed
return TRUE;
}
```

> **mysql_query**
>    ...excerpt from PHP manual Return Values
>
> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning
>   resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on
>   error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc,
>   mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Answer (score 1):

The `EXISTS` is faster then `SELECT COUNT(*)` because the subquery will stop searching when it finds one row. It won't have to find them all and count them. It will return either 0 or 1:

```
SELECT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT * FROM ... )
```

Comment: I am correct in understanding that I will still need to use `mysql_result`? And same question here: any advantage in using '`SELECT COUNT(*) ...`', '`SELECT COUNT(1) ...`' or '`SELECT COUNT(id) ...`'?

Comment: The link by mario explains the differences. `COUNT(*)` is usually faster than `COUNT(NotNullColumn)`. `COUNT(NullableColumn)` yields differnet result.

Comment: general rule on any rdbms is that EXISTS is the fastest way to go, not just MySQL