# difference between select count(*) and select count(fieldName)

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(*)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count)

As per subject, is there any difference in how MySQL interprets the above query? Or they are regarded as the same?

Comment: Have you tried them? They usually don't give the same results, so why do you think they might be considered the same?

Comment: sorry wrong title >.<, edited

Comment: Read this (almost identical question: [What is the difference between select count(*) and select count(any_non_null_column)?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2511/what-is-the-difference-between-select-count-and-select-countany-non-null-col)

Comment: This question has been asked millions of times.

Comment: They should be the same. It is preferred not to use `select *`. The most common problem I faced is what happens if you want to exclude a column? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between the functions `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(fieldname)` is that the second does not calculate NULL-values.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT *...` returns all the fields in the selected tables. `SELECT fieldname` returns only the specified field name.

It is more efficient using the second option, specially in cases where the table has many fields and some of them are not indexed. Selecting from those will take longer, and if you don't need there is no point in selecting all.

Comment: That isn't the question asked. The question is about `count(*)` vs `count(fieldName)`

Comment: This isn't the question now, it was when I answered, he changed the title

Comment: @MartinSmith: that was the question asked. Before OP edited it.

Comment: Ah, saw question after that then. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

select(*) means you wants to select all fields available in the table. While select(fieldname) means you only want to select certain columns in the table.

For example, you have a table 'Users' with columns 'username', 'email', 'password'; you can do the following:

```
select (*) from Users
```

which will give you all 3 columns (username, email, password); or you can do:

```
select username, email from Users
```

which will only give you 2 columns (username, email).