# SQL count function workings

Tags: sql

When you run a query like `select count(*) from myTable where (myVariable =1)` you get a number returned that fits that criteria.  If you replace the asterisk with any number, you get the same answer.  What's going on with SQL here?

Comment: You're getting the same count and that surprises you - so what did **you** expect instead??

Comment: `count()` should not take a number as parameter, but names of fields (or `*`).

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count

Comment: i expected the query to fail when you put something in there like count(343), not ignore it.

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its equivalent.

You are asking how many rows are in the table the number n will refer to the nth column in the table. Even if you don't have n columns this will work.

But it gets better you don't even need to put in anything relating to the table 
`SELECT ('X') from Table` is valid

There is a school of thought that SELECT(1) is better for performance but MSSQL at least the query optimzer looks after this by choosing the correct [plan](http://thehobt.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/debunking-myth-select-count-vs-select.html)

Comment: Thanks for answering the question instead of blasting it.  Will this take NULLS into account? Say if you do select count(5) and the fifth column is full of NULLS will it still return the number of rows in the table?

Comment: It doesn't. select count(5) from dual would yield an error then.

Comment: The query compiler ignores it.

Answer (score 1):

Count checks for non null values, so you can pass any value that has non null value e.g. *, field name, static value.

`COUNT(*)` will count every row. `COUNT(yourColumn)` won't include rows where yourColumn is NULL

[Refer many ways to use Count function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php)

Answer (score 1):

> Since the COUNT function will return the same results regardless of
>   what NOT NULL field(s) you include as the COUNT function parameters
>   (ie: within the brackets), you can change the syntax of the COUNT
>   function to COUNT(1) to get better performance as the database engine
>   will not have to fetch back the data fields.

Source: [SQL: COUNT Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most databases do *not* return the data fields for a count(*) versus a count(1).  This is a very basic optimization for the database optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

Little known feature is that you can query `select count(distinct someColumn) from SomeTable` to get the unique count of a certain column. Then it does matter wich column you pick obviously.

Else the other answers already explain it.

Answer (score 0):

`count(expression)` counts rows where  `expression is not null`.

If you try `count(1)`, then you'll get all the rows, as 1 is never null.

If you try `count(column_name)`, then you'll count rows where `column_name is not null`.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96540/functions26a.htm#82699