# Is there a difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(date_created)` in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm wondering if there is a difference performance wise between using `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(date_created)`. I've read that the only semantic difference is that `COUNT(*)` also includes `NULL` values, however the `date_created` field is not nullable in this specific case.

I've looked at various posts and none really answer this question for MySQL. The best I've found is a comment by @tsilb on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an index on `date_created`, there will be no difference.  If it's an unindexed column, you'll end up doing a full table scan.  When you have questions like this, you can find out a lot by using `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table` and comparing that to `EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(date_created) FROM my_table`.

Answer (score 2):

Count(*) is faster, as it does not require that the field be inspected.

Count(column_name) requires a table scan unless that column is already indexed.

Count(*) can just look at the primary key index.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `COUNT(*)` because dbms figures out which index to use for best performance.