# What is the difference between count(0), count(1).. and count(*) in mySQL/SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was recently asked this question in an interview.
I tried this in mySQL, and got the same results(final results).
All gave the number of rows in that particular table.
Can anyone explain the major difference between them.

Comment: Have a `null` value in a column. Then do a count on the column. See how the counts differ. Selecting `0` or '1` is just selecting a constant for each row, no `null` will be involved.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(\*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Nothing really, unless you specify a field in a table or an expression within parantheses instead of constant values or *

Let me give you a detailed answer. Count will give you non-null record number of given field. Say you have a table named A

```
select 1 from A
select 0 from A
select * from A
```

will all return same number of records, that is the number of rows in table A. Still the output is different. If there are 3 records in table. With X and Y as field names

```
select 1 from A will give you

1
1
1

select 0 from A will give you
0
0
0

select * from A will give you ( assume two columns X and Y is in the table )
X      Y
--     --
value1 value1
value2 (null)
value3 (null)
```

So, all three queries return the same number. Unless you use

```
select count(Y) from A
```

since there is only one non-null value you will get 1 as output

Comment: So why exactly are integral values passed to the count function?

Comment: @DhruvSingh gave you more detail in my answer

Comment: @Felipe Correa Considering Oracle there is not really any performance differences, if you get execution plan you will see Oracle runs all the same way. As eftpotrm says in his answer, back in the days it might not have been the same and count(1) or count(0) would be preferable. But now I doubt it would be different in any rdbms system.

Comment: It's not clear what counts if `A.X` will be `NULL` where `A.Y` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 52):

`COUNT(*)` will count the number of rows, while `COUNT(expression)` will count non-null values in expression and `COUNT(column)` will count all non-null values in column.

Since both 0 and 1 are non-null values, `COUNT(0)=COUNT(1)` and they both will be equivalent to the number of rows `COUNT(*)`. It's a different concept, but the result will be the same.

Comment: Thanks fthiella. @brhneser has a much detailled answer for a beginner like me.

Comment: Yes you are right but I think `count(*)` will take longer time than `count(1)`, is not it? If yes then using `count(1)` would be better for performance way. :)

Comment: @Yubaraj count(1) used to have better performances than count(*), at least on some dbms, but nowadays the optimizer is able to make count(*) equivalent to count(1)

Answer (score 19):

Now - they should all perform identically.

In days gone by, though, COUNT(1) (or whatever constant you chose) was sometimes recommended over COUNT(*) because poor query optimisation code would make the database retrieve all of the field data prior to running the count. COUNT(1) was therefore faster, but it shouldn't matter now.

Answer (score 6):

Since the expression `1` is a constant expression, they should always produce the same result, but the implementations might differ as some RDBMS might check whether `1 IS NULL` for every single row in the group. [This is still being done by PostgreSQL 11.3 as I have shown in this article](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/).

I've benchmarked queries on 1M rows doing the two types of count:

```
-- Faster
SELECT count(*) FROM t;

-- 10% slower on PostgreSQL 11.3
SELECT count(1) FROM t;
```

One reason why people might use the less intuitive `COUNT(1)` could be that historically, it was the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

The result will be the same, however `COUNT(*)` is slower on a lot of production environments today, because in production the db engines can live decades. I prefer to use `COUNT(0)`, someone use `COUNT(1)`, but definitely not `COUNT(*)` even if its lets say safe to use on modern db engines, I would not depend on the engine, especially if its only one character difference, also the code will be more portable.

Answer (score 1):

1. count(any integer value) is faster than count(*) ---> gives all counts including null values
2. count(column_name) omits null

Ex-->

column name=> id

values     => 1 1 null null 2 2

==> count(0), count(1), count(*) -----> result is 6 only

==> count(id) ----> result is 4

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have table with columns

```
Table 
-------
col_A  col_B
```

System returns all column (null and non-null) values when we query

```
select col_A from Table
```

System returns column values which are non-null when we query

```
select count(col_A) from Table
```

System returns total rows when we query

```
select count(*) from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql5.6

> InnoDB handles SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT COUNT(1) operations in the same way. There is no performance difference.

[12.19.1 Aggregate Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count)

Official doc is the fastest way after I found many different answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
COUNT(*), COUNT(1) , COUNT(0), COUNT('Y') , ...
```

All of the above return the total number of records (including the null ones).

But `COUNT('any constant')` is faster than `COUNT(*)`.