# SQL column to count grouped values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count, sum

I'm looking to display how many of the jobs in the job table that are being grouped by customer_id are approved.  Approval is determined if approval_date is not null.  So if there are 12 total jobs, I want to show that 7 are approved, for example.  If the approval date is null, the job is not approved.

```
select   
  c.customer_name
  ,count(*) as counts
  , -- i want to add a column here that tells me which jobs have (j.approval_date is not null)
from job j
join customer c on j.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_name
```

The code below gives syntax error:

```
,count(approval_date is not null) as is_approved
```

Comment: count(approval_date)?

Comment: Not quite -- the approval date must not be null in order for the job to be considered as approved.

Comment: `COUNT( expression )` only counts values, something NULL lacks as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368794/why-arent-nulls-counted-in-countcolumnname).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional sum:

```
select   
  c.customer_name
  ,count(*) as counts
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN j.approval_date is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
from job j
join customer c on j.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_name;
```