# Why would you ever use count('foo')?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have looked into the difference between:

```
count(*)
count(column_name)
count(1)
```

For example: here: [Count(*) vs Count(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/).  Some answerers also state: count('foo').  Why would you ever use count('foo').  It seems that this works:

```
select count('hello my name is joe bloggs and I finished school about ten years ago') from dbdisposals
```

Why would you ever pass a string to the count function?

Comment: The datatype of the constant is unimportant. Just that it is `not null` in some ways it might be less confusing than using an integer. E.g. New programmers might not realise that `count(0)` and `count(1)` do exactly the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In SQL, what's the difference between count(column) and count(\*)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59294/in-sql-whats-the-difference-between-countcolumn-and-count)

Comment: `count(1)`, `count('foo')` and `count('dracula')` are all the same.

Comment: @dystroy this is probably a dupe but not of that question.

Comment: @MartinSmith Of course it is. There's even the answer: "COUNT(*) returns the number of items in a group, including NULL values and duplicates.
COUNT(expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values."

Comment: This question isn't about `count(column)` it is about `count('string literal’)`

Comment: @MartinSmith a string literal is an expression which never evaluates to null.

Comment: I'm aware of that. Now go and read the other question and see where it asks about counting constants. Hint it doesn't.

Comment: The question is "Why would you use `count('foo')?`"  The answer is that the writer wants to count rows and inject a bit of individuality into the code.  I doubt it conforms to any known programming guideline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any literal value in the `count` has the same effect as `count(*)`, it counts the number of rows in the group. Using `count('str')` has the same effect as `count(1)`, i.e. it counts the records where the value is not `null`. As the literal value (`'str'` or `1`) won't be `null` for any of the records, it counts all the records.

The `count` function counts all non-null values, so a literal value in `count` has the same effect as `count(*)`, but `count(column_name)` counts only the non-null values in that column.

Using a string literal in `count` works fine, the only reason that you would avoid it would be that it might be confusing.

Comment: Thanks.  What does count(1) do? Is it the same as count(column_name), where column_name is the first column? +1.

Comment: @w0051977: No, `count(1)` simpy counts the records in the group where the value `1` is not `null`. As the literal value `1` won't be `null` for any of the records, it will count all records, just as `count(*)`.

Comment: @w0051977, the column name specification is semantically the same only of the column is `NOT NULL`.  If the column allows nulls and rows contain `NULL` values in the column, the results will be different because the `NULL` values are not counted.  There is no good reason to specify a column name when the intent is to count rows rather than non-null values.