# Get list of duplicate rows in MySql

Tags: sql, mysql

i have a table like this

```
ID     nachname     vorname
1       john         doe
2       john         doe
3       jim          doe
4       Michael     Knight
```

I need a query that will return all the fields (select *) from the records that have the same nachname and vorname (in this case, records 1 and 2). 
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following query will give the list of duplicates :

```
SELECT n1.* FROM table n1
inner join table n2 on n2.vorname=n1.vorname and n2.nachname=n1.nachname
where n1.id <> n2.id
```

BTW The data you posted seems to be wrong "Doe" and "Knight" are a lastname, not a firstname :p.

Comment: I just needed to add select distinct (the query was returning 2 times the same row). Thank you for your help

Comment: Note: if fields "vorname" and "nachname" are nullable then "coalesce" function should be used for comparison. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value/62260762#62260762

Comment: [@domis86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881774/get-list-of-duplicate-rows-in-mysql#comment117336762_2882047): or you could use the NULL-safe equal to operator (`<=>`), which compares nullable columns. Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Answer (score 13):

The general solution to your problem is a query of the form

```
SELECT col1, col2, count(*)
FROM t1
GROUP BY col1, col2
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This will return one row for each set of duplicate row in the table. The last column in this result is the number of duplicates for the particular values.

---

If you really want the ID, try something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM 
t1, 
( SELECT col1, col2, count(*)
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY col1, col2
  HAVING count(*) > 1 ) as t2
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Haven't tested it though

Comment: This would not actually return all of the rows, it would just find the duplicate rows.

Comment: This is way to expensive, you can solve it using a simple join (see my answer :p).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a self-join:

```
select distinct t1.id from t as t1 inner join t as t2 
on t1.col1=t2.col1 and t1.col2=t2.col2 and t1.id<>t2.id
```

the `t1.id<>t2.id` is necessary to avoid ids matching against themselves. (If you want only 1 row out of each set of duplicates, you can use `t1.id<t2.id`).

Comment: Nope, that one will only return 1 row with the 2 matching records in it, not the 2 rows that it should return...

Comment: @wimvds true, if you want all duplicate rows (instead of 1 row of each duplicate set, you should use <>)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table AS t1 inner join
(select max(id) As id,nachname,vorname, count(*) 
from t1 group by nachname,vorname 
having count(*) >1) AS t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

This should return ALL of the columns from the table where there is duplicate nachname and vorname.  I recommend changing * to the exact columns that you need.

Edit: I added a max(id) so that the group by wouldn't be a problem.  My query isn't as elegant as I would want though.  There's probably an easier way to do it.

Comment: Hmm... I see what you mean now. But I'm pretty sure your query is wrong. You can't return `id` if you're not using it to `group by`.

Comment: That join doesn't work - there's no `id` column in the t2 query.

Comment: This is just blatantly wrong... The group by will in fact eliminate any duplicates you have if you're using MySQL since you only group on nachname and vorname, so it will return 1 row, with 1 ID, instead of all distinctive rows as you probably expected (just try it, you'll see). Oh, and any other RDBMS would complain about your group by (which is imho the only correct way, I hate MySQL trying to guess what you want and execute these erronous queries instead of throwing an error).