# MySQL comparison with null value

Tags: mysql, sql, null, isnull

I have a column called CODE in a MySQL table which can be NULL. Say I have some rows with CODE='C' which I want to ignore in my select result set. I can have either CODE=NULL or CODE!='C' in my result set.

The following query does not return a row with CODE as NULL:

```
SELECT * from TABLE where CODE!='C'
```

But this query works as expected and I know it is the right way to do it.

```
SELECT * from TABLE where CODE IS NULL OR CODE!='C'
```

My question is why does having only CODE!='C' does not return rows where CODE=NULL? Definitely 'C' is not NULL. We are comparing no value to a character here. Can someone throw some light as why it doesn't work that way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL mystery: Null value is not different from non-null string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404766/mysql-mystery-null-value-is-not-different-from-non-null-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL mystery: Null value is not different from non-null string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404766/mysql-mystery-null-value-is-not-different-from-non-null-string)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In MySQL, `NULL` is considered as a 'missing, unknown value', as opposed to no value. Take a look [at this MySQL Reference on NULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html).

Any arithmetic comparison with `NULL` does not return true or false, but returns `NULL` instead., So, `NULL != 'C'` returns `NULL`, as opposed to returning true.

Any arithmetic comparison with 'NULL' will return false. To check this in SQL:

```
SELECT IF(NULL=123,'true','false')
```

To check `NULL` values we need to use `IS NULL` & `IS NOT NULL` operator.

Comment: In all relational databases, `null` is an unknown missing value.  Nothing mysql-specific about it.

Comment: But `NULL` is equivalent to `FALSE` in some situations.

So it can be annoying to debug and teh fix can seem rather longwinded and hackish.

Consider `UPDATE table SET name=? WHERE id=id AND name<>?`

You obviously mean, update if an update would change anything. But if name is null it will simply never update the row. A piece of missing data is not equal to some actual value, so of course it should return true and work.

Maybe DBs need a `NULL but TRUE` value type, similar to Perls `0 but true`.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski No, your example has not changed the nature of `NULL`. Your example provides a case where you want to *treat* `NULL` the same as a non-equal value. In that case, you could use `AND IFNULL(name, 'NOTMYVALUE')<>?` -- that's my understanding, anyway. The `ISNULL` function operates that way in MSSQL, and I believe `IFNULL` works similarly.

Comment: @Sam DeHaan: Yes, I was not very clear with that.
I think a better way to say what I was hinting at is:
MySQL has not been true to that description (which I think is a good one) of `NULL`. They have pretty much made the Not null-safe operators Null-safe. In my opinion they should fail and throw an error if they encounter `NULL`, not return 'NULL' which is basically treated as FALSE, as statements get executed on `TRUE` and do not on `FALSE` and `NULL`; In no other language would `if(NULL){}` be considered valid. In reality a 'missing, unknown value' `NULL`
 is no more FALSE than it is TRUE.

Comment: In my opinion, NULL-safe operators that make sense would be based on probability:
`NULL<>?`: An unknown value is almost certainly not going to be equal to some other value (`NULL` or otherwise) so this makes more sense to consider it `TRUE`. It is at least closer to true then it is to false.

`NULL=?`: An unknown value is almost certainly NOT equal to some other value, so true makes more sense here than anything else.

Comment: There is nothing different with how MySQL treats `NULL` and `UNKNOWN`. In all SQL implementations (Postgres, SQL-Server, Oracle, DB2) when the outcome of the `WHERE` clause is `UNKNOWN`, the rows are discarded from the results (and so do the rows where the outcome is `FALSE`).

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski And you can't say that *"an unknown value is almost certainly NOT equal to some other value."* If a value. unknown, then it could either be equal or not. We are not sure.

Comment: C'mon guys, this sucks. One would expect the following statement to be true `select TRUE != NULL`, this is like Javascript's `NaN`.

Answer (score 72):

Based on my tests and the documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html

You can compare null and get a boolean result using <=>
NOTE: it looks like NOT EQ operator, but it's EQ operator

For example:

```
select x <=> y; 
or
select @x <=> @y;
```

This also compares string vs null, string vs string, etc.

Comment: As @Alan_Fullmer mentioned "<=">" is an EQual operator . So if you want to check for NEQ (<>) then simply surround your statement with not. 
e.g. NOT(X <=> y).

Comment: TIL! Just a quick experiment: `select NULL = NULL;` returns `NULL`, and `select NULL <=> NULL;` returns `1`

Answer (score 20):

In SQL, the NULL value is a special value, not comparable with any other one.
The result of a direct comparison with a NULL is always NULL, although (unfortunately) you may find FALSE in some implementation.

To test a null value you should use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Often referred to as Ternary Logic.

Comment: The comparison of `NULL` to any value, even to itself is always `NULL` (or `UNKNOWN` in some implementations) but never `FALSE`. Where have you seen that behaviour?

Comment: @ypercube, I completely agree with you, but unfortunately such cases do exist. Look for example at the accepted answer of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843451/why-does-null-null-evaluate-to-false-in-sql-server .  and notice the "not true"

Comment: @comuz that answer is only talking about a specific system (SQL-Server) and a specific setting (ansi nulls off). Which makes SQL-Server treats nulls differently than the SQL standard dictates. If you mean that, ok. Otherwise, in SQL, `Whatever = NULL` results in `UNKNWON`.

Comment: Indeed, what I meant is that some implementations / settings can result in the comparison being FALSE/TRUE.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE IFNULL(`column_name` != 'C', TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```sql
SELECT * from TABLE where NOT(CODE <=> 'C')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from user where application_id='1223333344' and name is null;
```

Answer (score 2):

The specified problem can also appear in joins and the above answers aren't particularly helpful. The way I prefer to do it is by coalescing to otherwise impossible value. For example, this

```
   select foo from bar
     inner join baz on bar.x = baz.y
```

won't work if `bar.x` and `baz.y` are both nulls (join won't bring results). The workaround is to use e.g.

```
   select foo from bar
     inner join baz on coalesce(bar.x, -1) = coalesce(baz.y, -1)
```

where `-1` is "impossible" value meaning it can never appear in the data set.