# Mysql "where" filtering out null values without explicit statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i've noticed that this statement for example

```
SELECT * FROM mammals where animals <> "Dog"
```

Filters out all the rows that contains Dog on the column animals but ALSO filters out all the rows where animals is null.

Is that normal?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is.

You have to be null-safe when using nullable columns:

```
SELECT * FROM `mammals` WHERE COALESCE(`animals`, '-1') <> 'Dog'
```

Coalesce: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

If you were to use an equality comparison instead, there's a nullsafe operator for this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mammals` WHERE COALESCE(`animals`, '-1') <=> 'Dog'
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Related SO resource: [MySQL comparison with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9608639/1291428)

Note: `ISNULL` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) is another function similar to `COALESCE`. But the difference is that `ISNULL` is not ANSI standard and therefore should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Will this still use indexes efficiently? I think using `OR field IS NULL` would at least use an index, if this one can't.