# Can't receive results where field value is 0 or NULL

Tags: mysql

How to receive results from mysql table where field value is NOT `0` or `NULL`? If I write condition `field`!=1, it gives nothing, but there are a lot of fields where `field`!=1. Why?

UPDATE:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `somevar` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `somevar`)
VALUES
    (1,1),
    (2,0),
    (3,NULL),
    (4,NULL),
    (5,0);
```

This query

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `somevar`!=1
```

gives back only where `somevar`=0, but not NUL. how to echo all results where `somevar`!=1?

Comment: post your whole code, please. you should be able to select rows with `NULL` values. And try `WHERE field IS NULL`

Comment: if we assume somevar is null, 0 or 1 then you could use coalesce.  `WHERE Coalesce('somevar',0)!=1` but the null safe operator seems like the best solution.  I generally forget about the null safe operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL comparison with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered many times on this site. NULL Is neither equal nor not equal to anything else. It cannot be compared in traditional ways. You have to ask for NULL values explicitly.

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `somevar`!=1 OR `somevar` IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NULL-safe equal to operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```js
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `somevar` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `test`
    ->   (`somevar`)
    -> VALUES
    ->   (1), (0),
    ->   (NULL), (NULL),
    ->   (0);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `id`, `somevar`
    -> FROM `test`
    -> WHERE NOT `somevar` <=> 1;
+----+---------+
| id | somevar |
+----+---------+
|  2 |       0 |
|  3 |    NULL |
|  4 |    NULL |
|  5 |       0 |
+----+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ryq4XxVjmS7E8zN1Mr2cvK/0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `somevar IS NULL`. For mysql NULL is unknown value, therefore `NULL != 1` is `NULL` instead of `true`.  For detailed information you can look at [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `somevar` IS NULL OR `somevar`!=1
```