# C# MySqlCommand parameter with value of DBNull.Value not working

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, mariadb

Why is the value of DBNull.Value not working in the following code? I keep getting false as return value, while i am sure there is a record that matches.

(machineNumber has indeed the value of "b", so that is not the issue)

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `sparter` WHERE `id` = @machineNumber AND `account_id` = @null", conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineNumber", machineNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@null", DBNull.Value);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return reader.read();
            }
```

While this query IS working in MySqlWorkbench:

```
SELECT * FROM `sparter` WHERE `id` = "b" AND `account_id` IS NULL
```

Comment: Why should you use it in this way?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno how else?

Comment: In MySQL, dont use = or != with null.  They don't work.  Use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value

Comment: @Mark you are correct. my mindset was wrong. i wanted to use the dbnull.value, while i didnt needed to haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, in MySQL use `= or != null` don't work. Use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Can you try with this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * 
                                     FROM `sparter`
                                     WHERE `id` = @machineNumber AND `account_id` is @null", conn);
```

Comment: @Svenmarim Glad to help you :)

Comment: You might want to add WHY/HOW this works, as mentioned in the comment by @Mark .