# Feed back NULL value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

When withdraw table has no data `[Account No: 100.200.330.444]` and deposit table no data `[Account No: 100.200.330.444]`, then only show `NULL`.
But I want to show `0`.

I create virtual table 
and make `main balance`  `[Account No: 100.200.330.444]`
My Code like `deposit_amount - withdraw_amount  = Result`
When withdraws table empty, then feedback  `null`
I want to show main_balance =0

```
CREATE VIEW xyz as select account_no as account_no,
 CASE  
  when sum(deposit_amount)=null then 0
  when sum(deposit_amount)=0 then 0
ELSE sum(deposit_amount)
END
-
 (select  
  CASE  
   when sum(withdraw_amount)=null then 0
   when sum(withdraw_amount)=0 then 0
  ELSE sum(withdraw_amount)
 END
 from withdraws
  )as balance from deposits group by account_no
```

Comment: It may be simpler to change the schema so these amount columns are defaulted to `0` rather than NULL

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value

Comment: In SQL we normally use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` for testing for NULL values. `=` will not correctly test for null as null is considered a missing value

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be writing this query as a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT d.account_no, COALESCE(d.deposits, 0) - COALESCE(w.withdrawals, 0) AS balance
FROM (SELECT account_no, SUM(deposit_amount) AS deposits
      FROM deposits
      GROUP BY account_no) d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_no, SUM(withdraw_amount) AS withdrawals
           FROM withdraws
           GROUP BY account_no) w ON w.account_no = d.account_no
```

Note that I'm assuming that every account has at least one deposit (to open the account). If not, you will need to emulate a FULL JOIN instead (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql) for how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use arithmetic operators on a Null field. Null is `Unknown` hence `x = unknown` is always unknown.

if you want to check nulls you may use

1. `IsNull: i.e. IsNull(Field)`
2. `is null: i.e. Where Field is null;`
3. `coalesce: i.e. coalesce(Field, valueIfNull)`

Answer (score 0):

This is almost impossible to express accurately in a MySQL view because of the limits that MySQL places on views.  If you want all accounts, then start with the account table and use correlated subqueries in the `select`:

```
select a.account_no,
       ((select coalesce(sum(d.deposit_amount), 0)
         from deposits d
         where d.account_no = a.account_no
        ) -
        (select coalesce(sum(d.withdraw_amount), 0)
         from withdraws w
         where w.account_no = a.account_no
        )
       ) as balance
from accounts a;
```

MySQL does not allow subqueries in the `FROM` clause, which makes other formulations much more challenging.