# Laravel Where Clause not working for Null values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `customers` table and `Customer` as Model. I am trying to get all the customers except customer category with id 1. The `customer_category_id` can be nullable.

I have following query.

```
Customer::where('customer_category_id', '!=', 1)->with('customerMeta')->get();
```

Above query doesn't give the customers with null customer category id. What would be the reason ?

I need all the customers with category null or category not equals to 1

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value) for NULL comparison.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
Customer::where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('customer_category_id', '!=', 1)
                  ->orWhereNull('customer_category_id')
        })
        ->with('customerMeta')
        ->get();
```

Good luck!

Comment: If you need to fetch data that has either a valid value or null value, I guess this is the right way to start. Because all other solution using orWhereNull and stuffs are tricky and traps.

Answer (score 2):

Because `null` is also not equal to `1`. You should probably add `->whereNotNull('customer_category_id')` to your query:

```
Customer::where('customer_category_id', '!=', 1)
->whereNotNull('customer_category_id')
->with('customerMeta')
->get();
```

Comment: I have tried, but I need data with null category as well as with category not equals to 1

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question well enough. In that case your query should work  unless the relation for `->with('customerMeta')` is based off of the `customer_category_id` column

Comment: Customer meta is related based on customer id not customer category id

Answer (score 0):

That query should work.

You could try and run it in `artisan tinker`. Before you run the query activate query logging:

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
```

Then run the query.

Afterwards, run:

```
DB::getQueryLog();
```

You'll now see the query that was created. Copy this query into a SQL Client and tweak it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like this:

```
Customer::where('customer_category_id', '!=', '1')->with('customerMeta')->get();
```

Because the 1 also means `true`, so you have to use a string .

Comment: Bro, what's the difference from the query i have added ?

Comment: Please explain what you've changed and why, such that others can learn from it

Comment: Just try it. At most it will not work. But I think it will.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the `null` category as well, you can use `whereNull`

```
Customer::where('customer_category_id', '!=', 1)
->whereNull('customer_category_id')
->with('customerMeta')
->get();
```

or you can use multiple `where` clauses like this:

```
$query->where([
    ['customer_category_id', '!=', '1'],
    ['customer_category_id', '=', null],
    ...
])
```

Comment: You can't compare `null` with a `=`. You need to use `is` or `is not` depending on the context.

Comment: This will check for null category and not equals to 1 which will return empty result. I need null category or not equals