# Why "NULL is not equal to anything" is a false statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, null, mariadb, logic

I am sure I fail to understand (and may be accept) this, but can someone please bring comfort to my sense?

```
SELECT IF(NULL != 9, 'TRUE', 'FALSE')
```

*Am sorry if this is an inappropriate place for this, but StackOverFlow is the first thing came into my mind for an enlightment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL comparison with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost any comparison to `NULL` returns `NULL`.  This is because `NULL` has the semantics of "unknown value" rather than "missing".

When you have the comparison `9 <> NULL`, then the returned value is `NULL` (for the comparison).

`WHERE` clauses treat `NULL` values as "false" so rows get filtered out.  Similarly, `CASE` expressions treat `NULL` values as "false".

This is not always the case.  `CHECK` constraints treat `NULL` values as "true", so the check constraint passes even when the values are `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

A NULL in SQL means that it does not have a value. Any value. It is not less, equal or greater than any other value.

So:

```
NULL = 9  => null
NULL < 9  => null
NULL <= 9  => null
NULL > 9  => null
NULL >= 9  => null
NULL != 9  => null
NULL = NULL  => null
```

What is `TRUE` is `value is NULL` when the value is NULL.

Comment: What I fail to understand is, if NULL = UNKNOWN = never equals to ANYTHING, then WHY NULL is NOT equal to ANYTHING would come up as FALSE!

Comment: As said, `NULL` does not have any kind of value, i.e the value is undefined. So whatever value your compare it to, the result is `FALSE`. You cannot say a column is equal or not equal to something, if it simply is undefined.

Comment: NULL _might_ equal anything.

Comment: You might want to add `<=>` into your list.

Comment: @RickJames. The SQL92 stadard definition for NULL is:  "A null value is an implementation-dependent special value that is distinct from all non-null values of the associated data type.". So it cannot be equal to anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with `NULL` in the database, then you should consider the expressions as "trinary logic". That is, a boolean value does not evaluate to two values anymore (as in *binary*), but to three:

- **True**.
- **False**.
- **Null**: The SQL Standard is not clear about its definition, but it may mean the total absence of value, that the value is unknown, or it cannot be determined.

Now, take notice the `CHECK` constraint and the `WHERE` clause behave differently regarding null values. Consider the following example:

```
create table t (
  a int check (a <> 5)
);

insert into t (a) values (1), (2), (null);
```

**The WHERE clause**

A `WHERE` clause *accepts* a row if the predicate (the expression that represents the condition) is "true"; it *rejects* the row if the predicate evaluates to "false" or to "null".

```
select * from t where a = 1;
```

Result:

```
a
-
1
```

As you see, "null" was excluded from the result set since the predicate `a = 1` evaluated to "null".

**The CHECK Constraint**

The `CHECK` constraint works a little bit different than `WHERE`. The predicate is rejected when it evaluates to "false" only; it's accepted when it evaluates to "true" and also "null".

That's why it inserted all three rows, including the "null" value.

```
select * from t;
```

Result:

```
a
----
   1
   2
null
```

For the "null" value, the predicate `a <> 5` evaluated to "null" so it was accepted, and the row was inserted.