# Laravel cannot use field named 'status'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$this->model
            ->join('user_credentials', 'upload_conversions.user_id', '=', 'user_credentials.user_id')
            ->select(
                'upload_conversions.id',
                'upload_conversions.status',
                'upload_time',
                'user_credentials.user_id',
                DB::raw('CONCAT(user_credentials.first_name, " ", user_credentials.last_name) as user_name')
            )
            ->where('upload_conversions.status', '!=', 'x')
            ->groupBy('upload_time')
            ->get();
```

In the above query I cannot seem to use the field "status" in my where clause with Laravel's eloquent.

Please notice the "!=", it shouldn't matter what the string contains. If I change the where to use any other field, the query works like it should.

I cannot seem to find any answers and I cannot believe I'm the first to use a field name "status" in a where clause.

So what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: 
The problem is that i'm getting no error, but also no results. Where it should have plenty results. Changing the field in the where gives results..

UPDATE: 
It is because of NULL values. NULL in SQL should also not be a string so why is this not working? Is this a Laravel bug?

ANSWER:

```
->where('upload_conversions.status', '!=', 'test')
->orWhereNull('upload_conversions.status')
```

Really ugly, but this works.

Comment: What kind of error you are getting? please post the screenshot too.

Comment: No errors, but also no results, updated my questions

Answer (score 1):

You should use `'<>'` instead of `'!='` in where clause.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
->where('upload_conversions.status', '!=', 'test')
->orWhereNull('upload_conversions.status')
```

Really ugly, but this works.

Comment: `NULL` checks using `=`  is bad.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`whereNull`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses) to get NULL results.

```
->where('upload_conversions.status', '!=', 'test')
->orWhereNull('upload_conversions.status')
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608661/4964822) for more reference for NULL comparison.

Comment: Thanks, already did that in my code. This still feels bad though..

Comment: @bremg _bad_ for what reason?