# MySQL Query returns wrong result on NULL comparison and NULL Join

Tags: mysql

So I have a query

```
SELECT count(*) from table where  cat='green' and state = state and product = product
```

```
Result: 15000
```

Now when I run the same query with an additional condition that should result to true

```
SELECT count(*) from table where cat='green' and state = state and product = product and lga = lga
```

```
Result: 0
```

Pls what on earth could be wrong???
I assume that `lga=lga` should result to true just like `1=1` results to true

EDIT:
Table schema:

id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
cat varchar(128)    NO      NULL
state   varchar(8)  YES     NULL
lga varchar(20) YES  NULL
product varchar(150) NO NULL

To add some more context, I have a page with filters, so the only way I can ensure that the filters are flexible is to implement it the way I did.

Comment: You might want to add sample data and also show us the actual query (what you pasted above won't even run).  I'm not sure this is reproducible.

Comment: Show the table schema and some sample data that exhibit that problem... It makes no sense as currently written. Why would you compare a field to itself? That will always be true. So clearly you are not really doing that; maybe you are instead e.g. using a subquery and not realising what precedence aliases in different tables have.

Comment: If there are all NULLs in lga, that would do it. Can't check nulls for equality. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value

Comment: @MartinBurch is very correct. That is why Im having such results. You cannot check nulls for equality and the lga column contains null values for what I'm running.

Answer (score 2):

If the `lga` fields for all records where `cat = 'green'` are all `NULL`, this will happen because `NULL = NULL` will filter out all records. ["A NULL value is not equal to anything, even itself."](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-null/)

One approach I think you could take is to wrap the condition in [`ISNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
and IFNULL(lga,TRUE) = IFNULL('user provided input here',TRUE);
```

Please see fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c3a4/11