# MySQL how to select greatest of two column 0 and null

Tags: mysql

the table data like this, how to compare 0 is greater than null, and get the greatest value ?

| id | score_a | score_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | null |
| 2 | null | null |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |

I want the result like this

| id | max_score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | 1 |

I tired this, but the result is unexpected

```
SELECT greatest(coalesce(score_a,0),coalesce(score_b,0)) as max_score FROM table
```

| id | max_score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |

Comment: What is unexpected about that result

Comment: @RiggsFolly i want compare 0 > null, so the result should be 0, null, 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL comparison with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN COALESCE(score_a, score_b) IS NULL THEN NULL
         ELSE GREATEST(COALESCE(score_a, 0), COALESCE(score_b, 0)) 
       END max_score 
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c810016ced2f326bc1a6367ebd045658).
Results:

| max_score |
| --- |
| 0 |
| null |
| 1 |

Comment: work perfect ;), last question, will this cause bad performance ? because in the table has 3m records

Comment: @kenken9999 there is no WHERE clause to filter the rows because you want all of them, so the performance depends on on the number of rows.

Comment: yes, no where clause, got it, thankyou for your reply ;)