# MySQL Enum WHERE query not null returning incorrect rows

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I had a table that was created like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id INT, 
  name VARCHAR(20)
);
```

And let's say we inserted some data into it.

```sql
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1, 'John');
```

Later on, we introduced another column of type enum.

```sql
ALTER TABLE employee
    ADD COLUMN type1 ENUM ('REGULAR', 'PART_TIME');
```

Now, we inserted few more rows

```
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1, 'Dave', 'REGULAR');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(1, 'Bob', 'PART_TIME');
```

Now, the data in the table looks like this

```sql
'1', 'John', NULL
'2', 'Dave', 'REGULAR'
'1', 'Bob', 'PART_TIME'
```

If I run below query, I was thinking I should get rows 1 and 3.

```
SELECT * FROM employee where type1 != 'REGULAR'
```

But this returns only one row

```
'1','Bob','PART_TIME'
```

I tried this as well

```sql
SELECT * FROM employee where type1 != 'REGULAR' or type1 = NULL;
```

But this gave the same result.

1. Shouldn't the first query work as expected logically?
2. What can we way to write query to include NULL value rows as well?

Comment: The test for null is IS NULL

Comment: You should review what null is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL comparison with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608639/mysql-comparison-with-null-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM employee where type1 != 'REGULAR' or type1 is null;

SELECT * FROM employee where not(type1 <=> 'REGULAR')
```