# How to select a duplicated field in sql

Tags: sql, select

Guys how do i select a duplicated field in sql. I have a table with possible duplicates by title, how to select them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112618/finding-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
SELECT title, COUNT(*) as titleCount
FROM yourTableName
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: +1 . . . This is a very reasonable answer given the details in the question.  This is, however, standard SQL and should work in any database.

Comment: Thanks... I updated my comment to reflect that.