# Find duplicate rows in SQL Server by multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

My fields are

```
ID | Name | StartTime | EndTime | Date | Description
```

I am looking for a way to select all rows with the same entries in all fields except for the ID.

I am not that familiar with SQL so I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112618/finding-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server) approach but there is only one field relevant not (as in my case) five.

My first idea was to try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
order by Name, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Description
```

if I would look through all entries I would at least find the duplicates but that is definitely not the best way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
select Name, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Description
from   table
group by Name, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Description
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT ID, Name, StartTime, EndTime, Date, Description
FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID, Name, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Description) AS 'IndexNr'
        , ID
        , Name
        , StartTime
        , EndTime
        , Date
        , Description
    FROM Table) AS ResultSet
WHERE ResultSet.IndexNr > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below query.

```
SELECT     Name, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Description
FROM    Table
GROUP BY Name, Date, StartTime, EndTime, Description
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM TAB_NAME
HAVING COUNT(CONCAT(Name, StartTime, EndTime, Date, Description)) > 1
```

This will give you all the rows that are repeated except than the ID.

Comment: you can't use "HAVING" without "GROUP BY"

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I think the query is executable, you must give it a try first. Having is only used when we have to put a aggregate function in the cond. It has no relation with the group by claue. you must refer some docs for this.

Comment: ok, I am refering to some docs now. Look at all the other answers. Also your syntax would be slow if it worked. If you had 2 rows with the values: null, null, null, 'A' and 'A', null, null, null they would be considered identical in this match. You can not use wildchar eather while using a group by. So everything is wrong.