# In MS Sql-server, how to view additional columns of duplicates?

Tags: sql-server

Say I have a table with column `key` and column `date`. I'd like to view entries with duplicate `key` values along with their `date`. The below query will give the duplicate `key` values, but gives an error if I add `date` to my `SELECT` statement. How can I view the `date` of the duplicates?

```
SELECT key, count(*) FROM tbl 
GROUP BY
  KEY
HAVING 
 count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate rows in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112618/finding-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Paddy, I'm sure there's a duplicate somewhere on the site, but that isn't it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to achieve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
WHERE Key IN 
(
    SELECT key FROM tbl 
    GROUP BY Key
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl t
where exists
  (
    select 1 FROM tbl tt
    where tt.key = t.key
    GROUP BY KEY
    HAVING count(*) > 1
  )
```