# Duplicating rows in SQL output too many values

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I created a query to delete duplicate rows in a table. I tried to did this but the output was ”too many values”

```
DELETE FROM Employeetest 
WHERE employeeid IN (SELECT 
                         employeetest.*, 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY employeeid) AS rownumber 
                     FROM
                         employeetest 
                     HAVING
                         (rownumber > 1));
```

I did also

```
SELECT
    employeetest.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employeeid ORDER BY employeeid) AS rownumber 
FROM
    employeetest
```

then

```
DELETE * FROM employeetest;
```

It's not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate rows in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112618/finding-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you tagged as plsql that I understand your `DB` is `Oracle`. So you may use `rowid pseudocolumn` as in the following :

```
delete Employeetest t1
where rowid <
(
select max(rowid)
  from Employeetest t2 
 where t2.employeeid = t1.employeeid 
);
```

if the aim is deleting all the duplicates of `employeeid` values.

*P.S. It's not possible to delete in such a way `Delete * from employeetest where ...`, but using `Delete from employeetest where ...` or `Delete employeetest where ...` are possible options.*

Comment: @SarahAH If it worked and fixed your problem, you may wanna upvote the answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

I always use something like this:

```
delete employeetest
where  rowid in
       ( select lag(rowid) over (partition by employeeid order by null) 
         from employeetest )
```

Answer (score 0):

This logic is also commonly written as:

```
delete Employeetest 
where rowid in (select max(rowid)
                from Employeetest e2
                group by e2.employeeid
               );
```