# How to find duplicate entries in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find duplicate entries in the table but if I use `Code` only in the script then it will give me the duplicate entries in the table.

But I want to get all the information from the table including duplicate `code`.

Can someone guide me where I am doing wrong?

This results in 2 entries:

```
SELECT code, COUNT(code)
FROM CodeDefinition
WHERE codingSystem = '2.16' AND code='835002601'
GROUP BY code
HAVING COUNT(code) > 1
```

But when I tried the below script, it returns nothing.

```
SELECT code, COUNT(code), description, shortdescription
FROM CodeDefinition
WHERE codingSystem = '2.16' AND code='835002601'
GROUP BY code, description, shortdescription
HAVING COUNT(code) > 1
```

[duplicate rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmTEN.png)

Comment: Please show some sample data and define what your duplicate criteria is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding duplicate rows in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112618/finding-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: Hi @DaleK, I have added a screenshot. Please help me.

Comment: Please don't use images, use formatted text. I've added a link to an answer which solves your problem.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by description which is causing the issue. Please try this.

```
    SELECT a.code, b.cnt , a.description, a.shortdescription
    FROM CodeDefinition a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT code, COUNT(code) cnt
        FROM CodeDefinition
        WHERE codingSystem = '2.16' AND code='835002601'
        GROUP BY code
        HAVING COUNT(code) > 1
    ) b ON a.code = b.code
```

Comment: Unfortunately, without a minimal reproducible example, such answers provide a diminished value. Nobody can re-run it, test it, learn from it, and apply for any scenario.

Comment: Wouldn't an EXISTS be a better choice as far as performance? It would short circuit upon finding first duplicate, whereas using aggregation forces a table scan.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock How will I get the count with exists?

Comment: The OP didn't specify needing count (although yes it was in his example), just to find duplicates. But you can get the count with exists by using windowing functions COUNT(code) OVER (PARTITION BY Code).

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Oh Yes. Thank you. I will update the answer.

Comment: The EXISTS actually makes it WAY worse, don't do that after all :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try window function with cte:

```
with cte as
(
    SELECT code, COUNT(code)over(partition by code) CodeCount, description, 
    shortdescription
    FROM CodeDefinition
    WHERE codingSystem = '2.16' AND code='835002601'
)
select code,max(codecount),description,shortdescription from cte where CodeCount>1
group by code,description, shortdescription
```