# Find duplicate entries in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am writing this query to find duplicate CTN Records in table1. So my thinking is if the CTN_NO appears more than twice or higher , I want it shown in my SELECT * statement output on top.

I tried the following sub-query logic but I need pulls

```
  SELECT *
         table1 
   WHERE S_IND='Y'
     and CTN_NO = (select CTN_NO 
                     from table1 
                    where S_IND='Y' 
                      and count(CTN_NO) < 2);
order by 2
```

Comment: "more than twice or higher"? Surely duplicate records are those that appear more than **once**.

Comment: Related: [*Finding duplicates on one column using select where in SQL Server 2008*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13923387/3357935)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Using:

```
  SELECT t.ctn_no
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.ctn_no
  HAVING COUNT(t.ctn_no) > 1
```

...will show you the `ctn_no` value(s) that have duplicates in your table.  Adding criteria to the WHERE will allow you to further tune what duplicates there are:

```
  SELECT t.ctn_no
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
   WHERE t.s_ind = 'Y'
GROUP BY t.ctn_no
  HAVING COUNT(t.ctn_no) > 1
```

If you want to see the other column values associated with the duplicate, you'll want to use a self join:

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE x
  JOIN (SELECT t.ctn_no
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.ctn_no
        HAVING COUNT(t.ctn_no) > 1) y ON y.ctn_no = x.ctn_no
```

Comment: Adding the self join was a very useful addition.

Comment: @OMGponies can you please explain what the join does?

Comment: Wiithout the self join, you'll see the ctn_no column and its count. With the self join, you'll see all the other columns in YOUR_TABLE too.

Answer (score 4):

Try this query.. It uses the Analytic function SUM:

```
SELECT * FROM
(  
 SELECT SUM(1) OVER(PARTITION BY ctn_no) cnt, A.*
 FROM table1 a 
 WHERE s_ind ='Y'   
)
WHERE cnt > 2
```

Am not sure why you are identifying a record as a duplicate if the ctn_no repeats more than 2 times. FOr me it repeats more than once it is a duplicate. In this case change the las part of the query to `WHERE cnt > 1`