# Finding duplicates on one column using select where in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I am trying to select rows from a table that have duplicates in one column but also restrict the rows based on another column. It does not seem to be working correctly.

```
select Id,Terms from QueryData 
where Track = 'Y' and Active = 'Y'
group by Id,Terms
having count(Terms) > 1
```

If I remove the `where` it works fine but I need to restrict it to these rows only.

```
ID      Terms     Track    Active
100     paper     Y        Y
200     paper     Y        Y
100     juice     Y        Y
400     orange    N        N
1000    apple     Y        N
```

Ideally the query should return the first 2 rows.

Comment: I think some sample data would help illustrate your issue... I notice you're grouping by `Id`, is this column not unique in this table?

Comment: there are no indexes on this table and will provide sample above

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT Id, Terms, Track, Active
FROM QueryData
WHERE Terms IN (
                SELECT Terms 
                FROM QueryData
                WHERE Track = 'Y' and Active = 'Y' 
                GROUP BY Terms
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c19a9/1/0)

Data:

```
ID      Terms     Track    Active
100     paper     Y        Y
200     paper     Y        Y
100     juice     Y        Y
400     orange    N        N
1000    apple     Y        N
```

Results:

```
Id      Terms     Track    Active
100     paper     Y        Y
200     paper     Y        Y
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't exactly get what you're doing. You use `count(Terms)` in `having` however `Terms` is in your `select` clause. It means that for each records `count(Terms)` will be 1. Probably you have to exclude `Terms` from `select` list.
Honestly i reproduced your table and query and it doesn't work.

Probably [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afbea/7/0) is what you're looking for(?):

```sql
select Id, count(Terms) from QueryData 
where Track = 'Y' and Active = 'Y'
group by Id
having count(Terms) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return all duplicated terms meeting the criteria:

```
select Terms
from QueryData
where Track = 'Y' and Active = 'Y'
group by Terms
having count(*) > 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18a57/2

If you want all the details for these terms, you can join to this result.

```
;with dups as (
  select Terms
  from QueryData
  where Track = 'Y' and Active = 'Y'
  group by Terms
  having count(*) > 1
)
select
  qd.ID, qd.Terms, qd.Track, qd.Active
from 
  QueryData qd join
  dups d on qd.terms = d.terms
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18a57/5