# Find duplicate values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using this query to find duplicate values in a table:

```
select col1, 
       count(col1) 
  from table1 
 group by col1 
having count (col1) > 1 
 order by 2 desc;
```

But also I want to add another column from the same table, like this:

```
select col1, 
       col2, 
       count(col1) 
  from table1 
 group by col1 
having count (col1) > 1 
 order by 2 desc;
```

I get an `ORA-00979` error with that second query

How can I add another column in my search?

Comment: Add the second column to your group by: GROUP BY col1, col2 OR you can do a SELECT MAX(col2) instead

Comment: It will depend on what you consider "duplicate values" once you add the additional column.  Do you want to find cases where the combination of `col1` and `col2` are duplicated?  Or do you just want to take the data and logic from your first query and return an additional column of reference data?

Comment: @JustinCave No, I just want to know how many times I have the value of col1 in the table, col2 is just the id of the record.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find duplicate values in a table in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232/how-do-i-find-duplicate-values-in-a-table-in-oracle)

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld is similar but not the same, please read my question, I want to add another column in my query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query should be

```
SELECT * FROM (
select col1, 
col2, 
count(col1) over (partition by col1) col1_cnt
from table1 
)
WHERE col1_cnt > 1 
order by 2 desc;
```

Comment: almost there, it works but I got duplicate rows, anyway thanks

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want to get `col2` for each duplicate of `col1` that turns up. You can't really do that in a single query^. Instead, what you need to do is get your list of duplicates, then use that to retrieve any other associated values:

```
select col1, col2
from  table1
where col1 in (select col1
               from table1 
               group by col1 
               having count (col1) > 1)
order by col2 desc
```

---

^ Okay, you can, by using analytic functions, as @rs. demonstrated. For this scenario, I suspect that the nested query will be more efficient, but both should give you the same results.

---

Based on comments, it seems like you're not clear on why you can't just add the second column. Assume you have sample data that looks like this:

```
Col1 | Col2
-----+-----
   1 |   A
   1 |   B
   2 |   C
   2 |   D
   3 |   E
```

If you run

```
select Col1, count(*) as cnt 
from table1 
group by Col1
having count(*) > 1
```

then your results will be:

```
Col1 | Cnt
-----+-----
   1 |   2
   2 |   2
```

You can't just add `Col2` to this query without adding it to the `group by` clause because the database will have no way of knowing which value you actually want (i.e. for Col1=1 should the DB return 'A' or 'B'?). If you add Col2 to the `group by` clause, you get the following:

```
select Col1, Col2, count(*) as cnt 
from table1 
group by Col1, Col2
having count(*) > 1

Col1 | Col2 | Cnt
-----+------+----
[no results]
```

This is because the count is for each combination of `Col1` and `Col2` (each of which are unique).

Finally, by using either a nested query (as in my answer) or an analytic function (as in @rs.'s answer), you'll get the following result (query changed slightly to return the count):

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, cnt 
from  table1 t1
join (select col1, count(*) as cnt
      from table1 
      group by col1 
      having count (col1) > 1) t2
on table1.col1 = t2.col1

Col1 | Col2 | Cnt
-----+------+----
   1 |   A  |   2
   1 |   B  |   2
   2 |   C  |   2
   2 |   D  |   2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should list all selected columns in the group by clause as well.

```
select col1, 
       col2, 
       count(col1) 
  from table1 
 group by col1, col2
having count (col1) > 1 
 order by 2 desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of Error**

> You tried to execute an SQL SELECT statement that included a GROUP BY
>   function (ie: SQL MIN Function, SQL MAX Function, SQL SUM Function,
>   SQL COUNT Function) and an expression in the SELECT list that was not
>   in the SQL GROUP BY clause.

```
select col1, 
    col2, 
    count(col1) 
    from table1 
    group by col1,col2
    having count (col1) > 1 
    order by 2 desc;
```