# delete duplicate records except one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a replication of around 200 records in a table, I want to remove all of then except one, how can I do this ??

Comment: Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232/how-do-i-find-duplicate-values-in-a-table-in-oracle. If this is your case kindly close this thread.

Comment: @viki888, I am asking about deletion not to find duplicates :)

Comment: DELETE FROM Table WHERE (...your select query with limit 199...)

Comment: @rana,Did you try anything

Comment: table structure please

Comment: @mww, works thanku, but can you elaborate please

Answer (score 0):

Source [http://www.devx.com](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14665)

> It's easy to introduce duplicate rows of data into Oracle tables by
>   running a data load twice without the primary key or unique indexes
>   created or enabled.Here column1, column2, column3 constitute the identifying key for each record.

```
DELETE FROM our_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM our_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3) ;
```

Answer (score -2):

use the following query. This will be applicable if there is an Id available for the table.

delete from tableA where id in(select top 199 id from tableA)