# Find duplicate values in an Oracle table

Tags: oracle, duplicates

Have a table in an Oracle database called MESSAGE. This table has some fields, among them LOCALID and APPLICATIONNAME.

Here are examples of values entered in the database

```
LOCALID - APPLICATIONNAME
1       - app1
1       - app1
1       - app1
2       - app2
2       - app2
2       - app2
1       - app3
1       - app3
```

At certain times LOCALID is repeating itself to different APPLICATIONNAME.

I need to find all of these values that have different APPLICATIONNAME and LOCALID alike.

How to do an Oracle query for such a scenario?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find duplicate values in a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232/how-do-i-find-duplicate-values-in-a-table-in-oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't quite understand which of these two you would need so I included both:

A query to find duplicates:

```
Select localid, applicationname, count(*)
from yourtable
group by localid, applicationname
having count(*) > 1;
```

A query to find all distinct combinations or the two fields.

```
select distinct localid, applicationname 
from yourtable
```

**EDIT I**

I think I now understood.
This query will give you the localids that are allocated to more than one applicationname.

```
select localid, count(*)
from (
    select distinct localid, applicationname 
    from yourtable
) 
group by localid
having count(*) > 1;
```