# Oracle SQL - Select duplicates based on two columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select duplicate rows based on two columns in a join, and i can't seem to figure out how that is done.

Currently i got this:

```
SELECT s.name,administrative_site_id as adm_id,s.external_code,si.identifier_value 
FROM suppliers s
INNER JOIN suppliers_identifier si
ON s.id = si.supplier_id
```

And the output is something along the lines of below:

```
| Name       | adm_id      | external_code |identifier_value  |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------: |:----------------:|
| Warlob     |     66323   |    ext531     |    id444         |
| Ozzy       |     53123   |    ext632     |    id333         |
| Motorhead  |     521     |    ext733     |    id222         |
| Perez      |     123     |    ext833     |    id111         |
| Starlight  |     521     |    ext934     |    id222         |
| Aligned    |     123     |    ext235     |    id111         |
```

What i am looking for, is how to simply select these 4 rows, as they are duplicates based on column: adm_id and Identifier_value

```
| Name       | adm_id      | external_code |identifier_value  |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------: |:----------------:|
| Motorhead  |     521     |    ext733     |    id222         |
| Perez      |     123     |    ext833     |    id111         |
| Starlight  |     521     |    ext934     |    id222         |
| Aligned    |     123     |    ext235     |    id111         |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find duplicate values in a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232/how-do-i-find-duplicate-values-in-a-table-in-oracle)

Comment: In which table does the column `administrative_site_id` belong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First group by ADM_ID, IDENTIFIER_VALUE and find groups that has more than one row in it.
Then select all rows that has these couples

```
SELECT S.NAME
      ,ADMINISTRATIVE_SITE_ID AS ADM_ID
      ,S.EXTERNAL_CODE
      ,SI.IDENTIFIER_VALUE
  FROM SUPPLIERS S INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS_IDENTIFIER SI ON S.ID = SI.SUPPLIER_ID
 WHERE (ADMINISTRATIVE_SITE_ID, SI.IDENTIFIER_VALUE) IN (SELECT ADMINISTRATIVE_SITE_ID AS ADM_ID, SI.IDENTIFIER_VALUE
                                                           FROM SUPPLIERS S INNER JOIN SUPPLIERS_IDENTIFIER SI ON S.ID = SI.SUPPLIER_ID
                                                         GROUP BY ADM_ID, IDENTIFIER_VALUE
                                                         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: This does exactly what i wanted!
only had to change the GROUP BY to directly reference ADMINISTRATIVE_SITE_ID instead of ADM_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Or an alternate way that may perform better on big datasets:

```
with t as (
SELECT s.name,administrative_site_id as adm_id,s.external_code,si.identifier_value 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY administrative_site_id ,identifier_value ) AS cnt
FROM suppliers s
INNER JOIN suppliers_identifier si
ON s.id = si.supplier_id)
select name, adm_id, external_code, identifier_value 
from t
where cnt > 1
```