# Finding duplicates in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two table which am joining, but unable to find duplicates properly:

Below are 2 input tables:

[image: Input table 1]

[image: Input table 2]

[image: Output required]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find duplicate values in a table in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232/how-do-i-find-duplicate-values-in-a-table-in-oracle)

Comment: Please explain what YOU mean by "duplicate".

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this input? What duplicates are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to eliminate duplicates, which you can do using `select distinct`:

```
select distinct t1.id_number, t1.id, t2.id_type, t2.id_value
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.id;
```

Comment: Suppose all the vendors are giving (ID_number =A, ID_value=apple) while there is one outlier vendor which gives  (ID_number =B, ID_value=apple). Am searching for such cases where one ID_value is mapped to multiple ID_number. Since both the tables are combined with ID as common key. I tried below but can't get further select distinct id_number, id_value
from table a, table b
where a.id=b.id
and id_value is not null
group by id_number,id_value

Comment: @Nemesi7000 . . . Your comment doesn't seem very related to the question that was asked.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you want to do.